# VBA .CopyHere - Copy multiple files to ZIP file?

Tags: vba, vbscript, zip

The code below adds a folder called "Images" into my zip file. I don't want Images folder as a subfolder of the zip - how can I just add the contents of the Images folder to the root of the zip file? And `FolderToAdd & "*.*"` doesn't work.

```
Sub testing()
Dim ZipFile As String
Dim FolderToAdd As String
Dim objShell As Object
Dim varZipFile As Variant

ZipFile = "C:\ZipFile_Images\images.zip"
FolderToAdd = "C:\Images"

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
varZipFile = ZipFile

If Right$(FolderToAdd, 1) <> "\" Then
    FolderToAdd = FolderToAdd & "\"
End If

objShell.NameSpace(varZipFile).CopyHere (FolderToAdd)
End Sub
```

BACKGROUND: I pulled this code from a function that would add files one at a time to the given zip file, but when adding 100 small JPEG files, this would take a lot of time. Adding the whole folder at once is about 50x quicker.

Ultimately, I just want to be able to add multiple files at once natively so I'm open to other code snippets as well.

Comment: Every time you add anything to a zipfile it needs to be rebuilt from scratch. So adding individual files one at a time will be slow. Copy your files to a temp folder and zip the temp folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Ron de Bruin's page here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win001.htm

You should be able to adapt this.

Key part is:

```
oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(FolderName).items
```

Listing:

```
Sub Zip_All_Files_in_Folder_Browse()
    Dim FileNameZip, FolderName, oFolder
    Dim strDate As String, DefPath As String
    Dim oApp As Object

    DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        DefPath = DefPath & "\"
    End If

    strDate = Format(Now, " dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
    FileNameZip = DefPath & "MyFilesZip " & strDate & ".zip"

    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    'Browse to the folder
    Set oFolder = oApp.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select folder to Zip", 512)
    If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
        'Create empty Zip File
        NewZip (FileNameZip)

        FolderName = oFolder.Self.Path
        If Right(FolderName, 1) <> "\" Then
            FolderName = FolderName & "\"
        End If

        'Copy the files to the compressed folder
        oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(FolderName).items

        'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done
        On Error Resume Next
        Do Until oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).items.Count = _
        oApp.Namespace(FolderName).items.Count
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Loop
        On Error GoTo 0

        MsgBox "You find the zipfile here: " & FileNameZip

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Tim Williams answer, below is the edits to make my code work - note the two very small changes indicated by the commented lines.

```
Sub testing()
Dim ZipFile As String
'Dim FolderToAdd As String
Dim FolderToAdd
Dim objShell As Object
Dim varZipFile As Variant

ZipFile = "C:\ZipFile_Images\images.zip"
FolderToAdd = "C:\Images"

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
varZipFile = ZipFile

If Right$(FolderToAdd, 1) <> "\" Then
    FolderToAdd = FolderToAdd & "\"
End If

'objShell.NameSpace(varZipFile).CopyHere (FolderToAdd)
objShell.namespace(varZipFile).CopyHere objShell.namespace(FolderToAdd).Items
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

in maXbox , Delphi or ObjectPascal:

```
 var ShellObj,varZipFile: OlEVariant;
     sourcefolder: string;

 varZipFile:= zipfile;
 Shellobj:= CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');

 Shellobj.namespace(varZipFile).CopyHere(Shellobj.namespace(sourcefolder).Items)
```